# Updating included eager loaded associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, associations

I'm querying my Rails app for XML-encoded returns of some finds that have eager loaded associations.  Is there an easy way to do a bulk update of everything?  A preferable solution would be sending back modified XML with the same structure and calling an update() with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has [been implemented](http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/7/19/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-models) already!

Should be available in Rails 2.3 with a different syntax, according to the official [release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html#nested-attributes).

Here is the official [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).